# Exact sequence of tensor product(left exactness)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A,B be abelian groups and assume that A can be embedded into B.

Then we have a following natural exact sequence
$ \newcommand{\SES}[3]{ 0 \to #1 \to #2 \to #3 \to 0 } $
$$ \SES{A}{B}{B/A} $$

Let R be an arbitrary commutative ring.

After tensoring with R(over integer ring)

We get a following exact exact sequence

$ \newcommand{\SES}[3]{  #1 \to #2 \to #3 \to 0 } $
$$ \SES{A\otimes R}{B\otimes R}{(B/A)\otimes R} $$

In general, tensor product does not preserve left exactness.

My question is following:

If B/A is torsion-free(assume that B/A is nontrivial), then tensor product preserve left exactness?

Comment: If $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ or any Dedekind ring, yes. In general, no, the condition (which is called *flatness*) is significantly more subtle.

Comment: You could read up on the [Tor functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_functor). Specifically, you want to study $\operatorname{Tor}^{\Bbb Z}_1(B/A, R)$.

Comment: @Mindlack Can you give me a counter example? I cannot find a counter example since all the example I can imagine that break left exactness come from torsion in B/A

Comment: I think Mindlack's comment is about tensoring *over R*, not *with R*. If it's *with R* as in the question, then indeed $B/A$ being torsion-free is enough.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn’t read carefully enough. You’re tensoring *over $\mathbb{Z}$*. Then yes, flatness for an abelian group is being torsion-free. Sorry for being misleading.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you very much!